# getting the error: expected identifier for Network File Server

Tags: c, linux, file, server, client

I'm not sure how to fix this or what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to make a simple network file server and am kind of lost.

Here is what we've made so far.

I'm not sure if the server and client code are supposed to be in separate code files or if it's okay for both to be in the same code file like this one. The language is in C and it needs to be running properly in Linux environment. I keep getting this

> error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token {

The error is on line 49, so it's right after my second comment for the Client code.
Here is my code. Thank you for any help you all can give. I appreciate it.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <netdb.h>

// first we will create server

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    char sendBuff[1025];
    time_t ticks; 

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    listen(listenfd, 10); 

    while(1)
    {
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 

        ticks = time(NULL);
        snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
        write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff)); 

        close(connfd);
        sleep(1);
     }
}

//Now we will write the code for Client

{
    int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
    char recvBuff[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("\n Usage: %s <ip of server> \n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    } 

    memset(recvBuff, '0',sizeof(recvBuff));
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
        return 1;
    } 

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
    {
        printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
        return 1;
    } 

    if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
       printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
       return 1;
    } 

    while ( (n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0)
    {
        recvBuff[n] = 0;
        if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF)
        {
            printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");
        }
    } 

    if(n < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Read error \n");
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have no function name before the opening brace on line 49.

Answer (score 1):

Code to be executed should be inside function bodies.

You are using the variable `serv_addr` in the both blocks, so you will want another `{}` to surround the two blocks and put them inside one function body of `main()`.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <netdb.h>

// first we will create server

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ // beginning of the function body
    {
        int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

        char sendBuff[1025];
        time_t ticks; 

        listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
        memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

        bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

        listen(listenfd, 10); 

        while(1)
        {
            connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 

            ticks = time(NULL);
            snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
            write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff)); 

            close(connfd);
            sleep(1);
         }
    }

    //Now we will write the code for Client

    {
        int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
        char recvBuff[1024];
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

        if(argc != 2)
        {
            printf("\n Usage: %s <ip of server> \n",argv[0]);
            return 1;
        } 

        memset(recvBuff, '0',sizeof(recvBuff));
        if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        {
            printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
            return 1;
        } 

        memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 

        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

        if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
        {
            printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
            return 1;
        } 

        if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        {
           printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
           return 1;
        } 

        while ( (n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0)
        {
            recvBuff[n] = 0;
            if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF)
            {
                printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");
            }
        } 

        if(n < 0)
        {
            printf("\n Read error \n");
        } 

        return 0;
    }
} // end of function body
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! It now compiles correctly. I appreciate it MikeCAT!!